# Ensure an array, in TypeScript, contains all entries of a union of strings

Tags: typescript, types

Given a union of strings

```
type UnionOfStrings = "zzz" | "yyy";
```

how does one ensure there is an entry for every string in an array of objects?

```
interface Obj {
  a: string;
  b: UnionOfStrings;
}

const arrayOfObjects: Obj[] = [
  {
    a: "",
    b: "zzz",
  },
];
// Error: missing entry for `b: "yyy"`
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with an array of objects. The type information about what member of a union the object contains is lost as soon as you put it into an array. You could perhaps do it with tuples - but I'm not certain.

You could however write the type as

```
type UnionOfStrings = "zzz" | "yyy";
type MapOfObjects = { [k in UnionOfStrings]: { a: string, b: k } }

const arrayOfObjects: MapOfObjects = {
  zzz: {
    a: "",
    b: "zzz",
  },
}
```

which has the following error
`Property 'yyy' is missing in type '{ zzz: { a: string; b: "zzz"; }; }' but required in type 'MapOfObjects'.(2741)`

Comment: I believe question was about array of objects.

Comment: Yes @kinduser is correct, I'm looking for an array of objects, not an object of objects. But thank you for answering.